# How to implement variable-byte encoding algorithm in golang

Tags: algorithm, go

I'm doing some work with integer compression.
I've implemented variable-byte encoding algorithm in c++ (see the snippet below).

I wonder how to implement it in golang since I cannot convert `string` or `tune`
 type between `int` type in memory as `memcpy()` does.

Then, I've figured out `binary.Write()` in package `encoding/binary` can do the serializing work, which can encode uint8 into one byte, unint16 into 2 bytes, uint32 in 4 types and so on.

But how to encode a integer, which is between 2097152 and 268435456,  using only 3 bytes ?

Is there any similar converting method like the snippet ?

```
void encode(int value, char* code_list, int& len) {

  int bit_value = 0;
  int bit_num = 0;

  if (value < 128) {
    bit_num = 1;
  } else if (value < 16384) {
    bit_num = 2;
    bit_value = 1;
  } else if (value < 2097152) {
    bit_num = 3;
    bit_value = 3;
  } else {
    bit_num = 4;
    bit_value = 7;
  }
  value <<= bit_num;
  value += bit_value;
  memcpy(code_list + len, (char*) &value, bit_num);
  len += bit_num;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your encoding is such that the count of least-significant `1` bits in the first byte tells you how many bytes the encoded value has.

Here's a Go implementation of your code, that avoids depending on endianness (which your C version does), and uses an `io.Writer` rather than something like `memcpy`.

See it run at: https://play.golang.org/p/jr0NypSnlW

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bytes"
    "io"
)

func encode(w io.Writer, n uint64) error {
    bytes := 0
    switch {
    case n < 128:
        bytes = 1
        n = (n << 1)
    case n < 16834:
        bytes = 2
        n = (n << 2) | 1
    case n < 2097152:
        bytes = 3
        n = (n << 3) | 3
    default:
        bytes = 4
        n = (n << 4) | 7
    }
    d := [4]byte{
        byte(n), byte(n>>8), byte(n>>16), byte(n>>24),
    }
    _, err := w.Write(d[:bytes])
    return err
}

func main() {
    xs := []uint64{0, 32, 20003, 60006, 300009}
    var b bytes.Buffer
    for _, x := range xs {
        if err := encode(&b, x); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(b.Bytes())
}
```